# firebase get key value and store it in array

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I build ionic 3 app and I'm using firebase.
I have a structure of details that I want to get the key and value and store it in array.
some questions:

1. which kind of array I can do in typescript?
   2.I want to get the keys and the values of this structure:

   "Years": [

   1:"mechina",

   2:"Year A",

   3:"Year B",

   4:"Year C",

   5:"Year D"

   ],

the numbers are the key. what I tried , it give me only the values but i need to key also

```
this.collegeProvider.loadYears().on('value',years =>{
  this.yearsArray = years.val();
  console.log(this.yearsArray);
});
```

Comment: When you upload an array to firebase, it will be converted to object with keys as numbers and value as array items. And even you saved it as an object, a _.toArray() should help you get an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of the json structure you have provided but the firebase json tree looks something like this,

```
{
"-KsdJ5ngvltq1eOQJ6JS" : {
"a" : "",
"b" : "",
"c" : "",
"d" : "",
"e" : "",
"f" : "",
"g" : "kaushalagarwal79@gmail.com",
"h" : "",
"i" : "",
"j" : "",
"k" : ""
},
```

So while pushing your data in firebase you can code something like,
   
`myRef.push().setValue(new book(n, a, cn, cc, r, c, e, p, d, ed, pub, iE));
key = myRef.push().getKey();`

So in this case the key received is, -KsdJ5ngvltq1eOQJ6JS
U can create a array for numerous objects,

Hope that helps!!!